# get the href in the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wrote the below code. but it is not working.
how can I get a `href` in `li` because my code is correct but it can not find `a` in my function?

here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".PageNumber a").each(function(index, element) {
    var pagenum = $(this).next('.page').val();
    var linkk = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var linktext = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr(pagenum);
    $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page" />
```

Comment: `".PageNumber a` will search for `a` tag inside an element with `.PageNumber` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `a` inside the element with the class `PageNumber`.

`$(".PageNumber")` or even `$("a.PageNumber")` if you want to specify it a bit more

You also are looking for an `input` next to the `$(".PageNumber")`. But its next to the `li` so use `var pagenum = $(this).parent().next('.page').val();`

You are also using `$(this).attr(pagenum);` but not sure what you are trying to set or get the value of the attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".PageNumber").each(function(index, element) {
    var pagenum = $(this).parent().next('.page').val();
    var linkk = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var linktext = $(this).text();
    //$(this).attr(pagenum);
    $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `.PageNumber a` is looking for an `<a>` tag that is a child of a `.PageNumber` element. You do not have any such elements.

Use `a.PageNumber` instead. This looks for an `<a>` tag with a `PageNumber` class, which you *do* have.

Comment: you are using `.PageNumber a`  that means  anchor element is inside `PageNumber class`

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh: Birjolaxew isn't (the OP is). The point of the answer is to change that to `a.PageNumber` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

#### Explanation:

- As commented `.PageNumber a` will look for `a` tag inside an element with `PageNumber` class. Using `a.PageNumber` means any `a` tag that has `PageNumber` class. `li a.PageNumber` means, look for such element inside `li` tag.
- When you work with `data-` attribute, you should use `.data` api, as it is meant for such usage.
- This `var pagenum = $(this).next('.page').val();` will not work as `a` is the only element. You can either use `.parent` if the structure is going to be fixed, or use `.closest('li')` if it can change. Then move to next element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li a.PageNumber").each(function(index, element) {
   console.log($(this).data('href'))
   
    var pagenum = $(this).closest('li').next('.page').val();
    var linkk = $(this).attr("data-page");
    var linktext = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr(pagenum);
    $(this).text(pagenum);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="page" />
<li><a class="PageNumber" data-page="" data-href="home.htm">1</a></li>
<input type="hidden" value="3" class="page" />
```

---

Apart form that, I'm not sure what your are doing in this line: `$(this).attr(pagenum);`. `pagenum` will hold values like `1`, `2`. You do not have any such attribute in you element. You are not even assigning it to a variable. So you are neither setting nor getting value of some attribute.

Comment: Why to try that?? Plz Explain

Comment: @Durga, I have updated my answer. Please feel free to point any inconsistencies/ missing information.

Answer (score 0):

If the li above is having just one anchor each, then probably just use 
$('li a') as the selector or in above case $('a. PageNumber'), one more suggestion avoid camel case keywords for class names.Try to use hyphen separated class names.

Comment: `$('a. PageNumber')` what this will return ?

Comment: The space will not be good since it will then look for an element within an `a`